# GDI Objects With Event Handlers in Local Scope

Tags: c#, multithreading, gdi

I have a quick question that I have been unable to find an answer elsewhere.

We have a large 4.0 desktop application (think around 100 projects between 3 solutions) that is experiencing 10k+ GDI Object issues. Obviously we have leaks somewhere. I've been doing a *lot* of testing lately to figure out exactly what might be the issue. Some of it is .NET, for instance, every single new instance of a TabControl, even disposed, appears to leave behind one GDI Object (each open/close of the form increased from 79 objects to 80, then 81, then 82, etc.) but obviously our users are not opening up forms with tab controls 10,000 times a day each.

Onto my question: do I have to release event handlers for local scope code such as below:

```
            UserLoginManager loginManager = new UserLoginManager();
            loginManager.LoginFailed += HandleFailedLogin;
            loginManager.LoginSuccessful += HandleSuccessfulLogin;

            loginManager.LogUserInAsync(this.UserNameTextBox.Text.Trim(), this.PasswordTextBox.Text.Trim());
```

I ask this because I don't know for sure if the object will be GC'd correctly if there are event handlers assigned to, say, a form that remains open for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Are you drawing something by yourself (creating brushes and not freeing them)? A custom control or something inside an existing control? Why are you think that your GDI Leak comes from the code you're showing us?

Comment: I don't. I'm trying to rule it out as a possibility. 

We do have static methods for copying images (greyscale and TIFF) from check scanners (unmanaged 32-bit driver), but I was able to rule that out. No matter how many times I copied the images using that method, the total GDI objects remained at 82.

Comment: No.  You are not going to fix a problem that's been ignored for years in a single day, especially given that you have no idea where to start looking.  Talk to your supervisor, you are going to have to spend money.  At least a static code analyzer and a memory profiler that can diagnose handle leaks.  Aim high, also ask for time.

Comment: Maybe you finde here a guide to start searching your problem: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak/ especially on the end is a list of common mistakes.

Comment: I appreciate the comments.

Please note that I am not asking for help in tracking down the issue in its entirety. I started on this project a decade ago (I'm the lead) and it's not something that is solved in a day. I just wanted to know if it's vital to unregister event handlers in a local scope variable such as above, or it is completely fine to leave those in place. Will GC pick that up and dispose of the object and all references when it leaves scope? Knowing that for sure means I can cross off a huge amount of our codebase.

Comment: That code above doesn't show much, you'll have keep debugging/profiling until you can isolate smaller section(s) in your codebase that do show the leak.

Comment: Just forget it, I'll figure out a way to test for this myself. Seriously, I just asked a simple question: do I have to unregister event handlers for a local variable when they're attached to a app-life-long reference before it moves out of scope or not. That's it, and what I get is "we can't figure out your leak for you". I didn't ask you to. I just wanted to cross something off my list of possibilities since I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere else.

Comment: They're trying to tell you they can't rule that out based on the code presented.

Comment: Although it's not entirely related - yes, I was able to determine through testing that references with event handlers can fall out of scope and be collected properly. I did, however, discover a class that is the base of all of our headers for controls that creates a number of brushes & pens that are not disposed of. That is likely to be the source of our leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GC only chases references in one direction. The event handler delegates you're registering will have a reference to the form (if they're instance methods), and the event itself holds references to the delegates. But if nothing is holding a reference to the `UserLoginManager` then it will be eligible for collection and the references it is (transitively) holding won't keep other objects alive.

The risk with event handlers and leaks is the opposite way around - if you have a long-lived object that exposes events and you have objects that *want* to be short-lived - if those "should be short-lived" objects register event handlers and fail to unregister them later than *that* will prolong their lifetimes.